# Facebook Graph request for profile data returns no name

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I use Facebook to login to my iOS app, and the main part of this involves getting the user's name.

For some users, using Facebook SDK 3.x and 4.0, I receive no name in the result returned from my Facebook Graph request.

```
FBSDKGraphRequest *detailsRequest = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:@{@"fields": @"name,id,picture,gender,birthday,email"}];
[detailsRequest startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *detailsError) {...}];
```

This is what I'm using at the moment. All other fields are returned, but not "name". I presumed every user would have to have a name on Facebook, is there a permissions issue or am I doing something wrong?

For what it's worth, the SDK doesn't log any errors back to me.

Comment: Can you provide the ID of a particular user for which you get no name? I believe deprecated grey account logins (shared company logins) sometimes have no names.

Comment: @daviddoran I'd rather not share someone's ID here...but thanks for the info. Do you know what causes the deprecation, or is there a way to modernise these logins?

Comment: Hi Ricky, by deprecated I mean that we no longer allow grey accounts to be created and they soon won't be useful for anything. Companies now use Business Manager to manage how employees access company-owned Facebook Pages and apps. Without seeing a user ID (and I completely understand your reasoning) a grey account is my best guess for why name is missing.